# How to put a static local image in html template in Errai Framework?

Tags: html, errai

I have html template, and I would like to use inside an image as follow:

```
<img src="img/Avatar.png">
```

I use errai in version: 4.0.0.CR1.
I've checked documentation, but there is no word about it.
What path should be set for local image's in template file?
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No magic. The path is related to your root document. I mean index.jsp or index.html. So you can simply use relative or absolute path to your image as for regular web page.

Let's assume your app starts like this: http://127.0.0.1:8888/. Then simply "/img/Avatar.png" should work fine.

If your app starts like this: http://127.0.0.1:8888/App/, then simply "/App/img/Avatar.png".

But of course I would recommend properly resolved relative path.